# Copy variable value labels

Tags: stata

I have two datasets, or .dta files. One has certain variables where each value has a corresponding label. The other datafile has no value labels, but the values of the variables are similar to certain variables in the first datafile. What I want is to copy those value labels from the first file to the second file.

Comment: You might be better off sending this question to statalist.

Comment: Additional links to Stata resources can be found at http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/794.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at -label save-. This saves the labels as a do-file that you can use on your second data set.